# Get difference between columns(EndTime - BeginTime)

Tags: mongodb

I want to find difference between 2 date columns(EndTime - BeginTime). Document is as below:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("586b0dca49631626615cf0d1"), "ProcessData" : { } }
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("586a299570f4015775000000"),
        "ProcessData" : {
                "09-OutputReports" : {
                        "EndTime" : ISODate("2017-01-02T12:59:47Z"),
                        "BeginTime" : ISODate("2017-01-02T10:21:14Z")
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: No...I want to compare in same document, not any other doc.

Comment: Read their [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/)